# $x+ky \in W$ if and only if $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W \subset V$ with $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$
I'm asked to prove $x+ky \in W$ if and only if $W$ is a vector subspace of V, for all $x$, $y\in W$, for all $k \in \mathbb{K}$.
I know this to be true when you take an arbitrary linear combination of the two vectors, which is why I found it weird when I found it in a homework question. Is it a mistake? Since this doesn't seem to tell us anything about scaled multiples of $x$, which may or may not be in the subset $W$

Comment: No I don't think it is a mistake, $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if and only if $x+ky$ is in $W$ for all $x,y \in W$ and for all $k$ in $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by setting $k=1$ we get $x+y \in W$, which gives us closure under addition. We also get $x - x = 0 \in W$ by setting $k=-1, y=x$. Since $0$ is in $W$, we set $x=0$ to get $ky \in W$ which gives us closure under multiplication by scalars. So we conclude by the subspace theorem that $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$.

Comment: Interesting. Any insight as to why is it more common to use an arbitrary linear combination of vectors of $W$ to determine if $W$ is a vector subspace as opposed to the one you just showed?